# Script that make folders and files in every folder

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Do you have any idea how would a script in shell would look like with the following conditions:
When executed, it has to make
Folders with specific numeration
In every folder, it has to make blank file from 0-9

And on top of all, another directory has to be made with a file in it counting how many files are in each directory?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `counting how many files are in each directory?` - if in each folder there are blank files from 0-9, each folder will have 10 files....

Comment: No, in total. The last directory will be called A-Z and in it will be file containing the total number of files of all directories.

Comment: So it's 260 files?

Comment: Exactly. It must say that from directory A to directory Z total ammount of files inside them are 260.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell-script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0

for x in {A..Z}; do
    mkdir ${x}
    pushd ${x} > /dev/null || exit 1
    for y in {0..9}; do
        count=$((count + 1))
        touch $y
    done
    popd > /dev/null || exit 1
done

mkdir counter
echo $count > counter/result
```

Is that what you're looking for?

**What is happening?**

We range over the characters A to Z and create a directory named with the current character.

`pushd <dir>` navigates into the directory. ( `> /dev/null` suppresses the pushd's logging)

Now as we are in the newly created directory, we can create the files 0..9 by invoking touch on that filename.
In here we can also increase the counter since we just created a file.

After creating all ten files, we move back to the directory we came from by using `popd` and continue with the loop.

Comment: It works just as expected. Thank you alot. Can you please explain to me how this works? I managed to create the directories with
for char in {A..Z}; do
But seem to not find out how to create the files in every one of the directories in one line.

Comment: I edit the answer to explain the basic steps. Does it help you?
The trick is to move into the newly created directory with `pushd/popd`.

Comment: And I just added ` || exit 1` to both pushd and popd, so we exit the script when one of those commands fail.